# Update columns with duplicate values from the DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a data set which has values for different columns as different entries with first name to identify the respective columns.
For instance James's gender is in first row and James's age is in 5th row.

DataFrame
`df1`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight in lb | Height in cm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James |  | Male |  |  |
| 1 | John |  |  | 175 |  |
| 2 | Patricia | 23 |  |  |  |
| 5 | James | 22 |  |  |  |
| 4 | James |  |  | 185 |  |
| 5 | John | 29 |  |  |  |
| 6 | John |  |  |  | 176 |

I am trying to make it combined into one DataFrame as below
`df1`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | 22 | Male | 185 |  |
| 1 | John | 29 |  | 175 | 176 |
| 2 | Patricia | 23 |  |  |  |

I tried to do groupby but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming NaN in the empty cells, you can use `groupby.first`:

```
df.groupby('First Name', as_index=False).first()
```

output:

```
  First Name   Age Gender  Weight in lb  Height in cm
0      James  22.0   Male         185.0           NaN
1       John  29.0   None         175.0         176.0
2   Patricia  23.0   None           NaN           NaN
```